# Render multiple MJML files into one MJML file/string

Tags: node.js, mjml

I am in the process of converting some legacy email templates to `mjml` (using mjml version 4.2). I am using Azure Function (NodeJs) to dynamically add content to templates using handlebars and return me the final `html email`, which works great. I have separated sections of the template into different files (header, footer, intro etc.) and I have included them using `mj-include`.

currently this is what I'm doing.

- I first read the main mjml file.

  var mjmlData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
- then run `mjml2html` to get the template rendered

  var htmlTemplateObject = mjml2html(mjmlData, {filePath: filePath});
- Then I run handlebars to inject dynamic content

  handlebars.compile(htmlTemplateObject.html)(req.body.data)

I have to run mjml2html first before using handlebars to inject data dynamically as otherwise handlebars won't pick content in the files that I have included with `mj-include`. Because of this, if I have for example say a `p` tag in the dynamic content, the styles won't get inlined because I have already converted my `mjml` template to `html` before running `handlebars`.

Is there a way for me to get the full `mjml` (with content from file included using `mj-include`) rendered into a string before running `mjml2html`?

Any help much appreciated as something like `mjml2string` would make this a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the `mjml` `github` repository to find out how it works as `MJML CLI` needs to somehow combine the files in `mj-include` elements before converting it to `html`. I found the code which include the files and generate the `MJML` document in `mjml-core/lib/includeExternal`.

All I had to do was to import it and use it as

```
let mjmlTemplate = mjmlInclude(mjmlBaseTemplate, {filePath: mjmlBaseTemplateFilePath})
```

Then I ran handlebars to inject dynamic content into the template and finally run `mjml2html(mjmlTemplate)` to get the final html file. Doing so injected my styles within `mj-style` to `html` tags in the dynamic content.

Comment: Impressive! Can anyone update this technique? Has there been related MJML refactoring since then (4.2 to 4.10.1?) Is the above line an `mjml2mjml-with-includes`? Then use `mjml2html` and `handlebars`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim the answer as mine, but it serves as an update to the above. I saw this on the MJML Slack from the MJML team. Applies to source code for MJML 4.10.1.

> Hi !
> You can use the mjml parser as we use it in mjml-core here
> https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-core/src/index.js#L128-L135
> and convert back the json to xml (we have a internal helper for that too
> https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-core/src/helpers/jsonToXML.js )
>
> Don't forget to require the full mjml package first to load register every standard components